# Error in Targeting Company Shares Using JSON

Tags: json, linkedin-api

I'm trying to Target company shares (https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/targeting-company-shares) using json with LinkedIn Rest Api.

My JSON object (https://developers.linkedin.com/forum/targeting-example-using-multiple-targeting-parameters-and-json) looks like :

```
{
"visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
},
"comment": "Targeting Shares",
"share-target-reach": {
    "share-targets": {
        "share-target": [{
            "code": "geos",
            "tvalues": {
                "tvalue": "as"
            }
        }, {
            "code": "companySizes",
            "tvalues": {
                "tvalue": "201-500"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}

But this isn't working, i'm getting the following error :

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Malformed json document. Encountered unexpected array.",
  "requestId": "DRWYRUVMBJ",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1423283491818
}
```

I'm not able to figure out where's the problem??

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with this for awhile now and near as I can tell the below format will work. Basically you have to remove all the arrays, I have tried them at every level and they always cause the malformed json error. I still have no idea how to target multiple sections at once though, since the [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#targetting_shares) on this is very wrong. The only way I figured this part out is by doing a whole lot of guessing.

```
{
"visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
},
"comment": "Targeting Shares",
"share-target-reach": {
    "share-targets": {
        "share-target": {
            "code": "geos",
            "tvalues": {"tvalue": "as"}
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Update: After playing around with it more it looks like the XML example in their documentation is correct. Using that as a template I was able to post to multiple different segments at once.